# Flux from iterable how to handle back pressure

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactor

I need to handle back pressure in my flux, that receives as input a List of object. The size of the list varies from few hundreds to some hundreds of thousand elements. 
The actual code is:

```
Flux.fromIterable(alarms)
            .limitRate(parallelism)
            .parallel(parallelism)
            .runOn(Schedulers.elastic(), bufferSize)
            .doOnNext(reactiveHandleDataService::handleAlarm)
;
```

The parameter "limitRange" simply force to refuse a list over a certain size, thing that I don't want. I need all the data received to be given to reactiveHandleDataService, I can't lose a message.

How can I handle back pressure in this case? I did't find much example explaining well the problem, especially using an iterable as source.

I'm using Californium-SR3 as release of reactor and this is part of a spring boot application.

Comment: Where does that list of items come from? If you already have everything in a `List`, what is the point in applying [backpressure](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure-(2.0)) ?

Comment: I need backpressure to not overload the method handleAlarm and consequently not to saturate the connection pool used in handleAlarm.

Answer (score 0):

is handleAlarm job to have backpressure if cant support to many data to send request for new data after processing 1. if you cant have backPressure to handleAlarm you can add delay

```
Flux.fromIterable(alarms)
        .limitRate(parallelism)
        .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(10))
        .doOnNext(reactiveHandleDataService::handleAlarm)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulars.elastic)
```

;

and if you want backpressure why you are running in parallel

Comment: I need something, perhaps is not back pressure the solution, that allows to control the flow of data from the flux to the next step. It could be that I need only to tune better the parallelism, I don't know, I'm new to reactor, so I'm trying to evaluate all the opportunities.

Comment: in my case you set to delay the time of emitting if handle-alarm can process 1 item for 10 mili you will emit only 1 item in 10 mili and not lose any data @Stefania

Comment: If the size of alarms is bigger than "parallel", the "limitRate" disallow the flux to elaborate the list of alarms, discarding them.